# How to make ibooks automatically break sentences?

Tags: epub, apple-books

I have an epub file which I tested in ibooks to see if the layout is right.
It opened perfectly, but I noticed that lines/sentences that are broader than the screen, are not broken down and shown on the line below.
So only a part of the epub is readable. The rest simply cannot be seen. How can I adjust my epub so this issue will be solved?

So: how to make it "responsive" to the screen size?

Edit: text / formatting of one html page in the epub:
Just a part. There is a lot lot more and I believe most of it is crab. Problem is I do not know which part... 
it's in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/eW4nXgYY

most of it is like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  }

  @font-face{
  font-family:"宋体";
  }

  @font-face{
  font-family:"Wingdings";
  }

  @font-face{
  font-family:"Arial";
  }

  @list l0:level1{
  mso-level-number-format:bullet;
  mso-level-suffix:tab;
  mso-level-text:\F06C;
  mso-level-tab-stop:none;
  mso-level-number-position:left;
  margin-left:18.0000pt; text-indent:-18.0000pt; margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt; font-family:'Wingdings'; }
```

but then a zillion times repeated..

this is the code for the actual text:

```
<body style="tab-interval:21pt; text-justify-trim:punctuation;">
  <!--StartFragment-->

  <div class="Section0" style="layout-grid:14.3500pt;">
    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">Zondag&nbsp;1</span></p>

    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">Vraag&nbsp;1:&nbsp;</span></p>

    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">Wat&nbsp;is&nbsp;uw&nbsp;enige&nbsp;troost&nbsp;in&nbsp;leven&nbsp;en&nbsp;sterven?&nbsp;</span></p>

    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;</span></p>

    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">Antwoord:</span></p>

    <p class="p17" style="margin-bottom:0pt; margin-top:0pt;"><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">Dat&nbsp;ik&nbsp;met&nbsp;lichaam&nbsp;en&nbsp;ziel,&nbsp;in&nbsp;leven&nbsp;en&nbsp;sterven</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:8.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman'; vertical-align:super;">1</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">,&nbsp;het&nbsp;eigendom&nbsp;ben,&nbsp;niet&nbsp;van&nbsp;mijzelf</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:8.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman'; vertical-align:super;">2</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">,&nbsp;maar&nbsp;van&nbsp;mijn&nbsp;trouwe&nbsp;Heiland&nbsp;Jezus&nbsp;Christus</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:8.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman'; vertical-align:super;">3</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">.&nbsp;Want&nbsp;Hij&nbsp;heeft&nbsp;met&nbsp;zijn&nbsp;kostbaar&nbsp;bloed&nbsp;voor&nbsp;al&nbsp;mijn&nbsp;zonden&nbsp;volkomen&nbsp;betaald</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:8.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman'; vertical-align:super;">4</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">&nbsp;en&nbsp;mij&nbsp;uit&nbsp;alle&nbsp;macht&nbsp;van&nbsp;de&nbsp;duivel&nbsp;verlost</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:8.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman'; vertical-align:super;">5</span><span style="mso-spacerun:'yes'; font-weight:normal; font-style:normal; font-size:12.0000pt; font-family:'Times New Roman';">.</span></p>
```

Comment: The code in your EPUB is a bunch of remnant garbage from Microsoft Word - the data can be helpful in retaining information that then must then be massaged into correct XHTML - but left as is it should absolutely not be in a final EPUB file. What is the origin story behind this EPUB file?

Comment: Also - have you tried using a validator to validate this EPUB?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've got a reflowable epub formatted semantically, it should do this automatically. I've seen some conversions that used tables to lay out text rather than simply putting each paragraph in a `<p>` tag, and that can have the result you describe. To be any more specific, I'd have to have a look at your code. If you update your post with a relevant section of HTML and CSS, I'd be happy to do so.

EDIT: From what you've posted, it looks like all the spaces in the epub have been replaced with non-breaking spaces. These are space characters that do not function as word boundaries, so lines don't break at them. They are represented by `&nbsp;`.

There may be more going on in the chaos that comes from an auto-generated epub file--for starters, you might check to see if hyphenation is disabled in the CSS.

One thing you might try is opening up this HTML file in Chrome and see if it looks the same as it does in your devices. If it does, hit shift-ctrl-j to open the developer tools, go to the Elements tab, and then select a particular paragraph that runs off the screen. The Dev tools section should show a list of all the styles that are applied, with checkboxes to temporarily turn them off. At that point, is just a matter of experimenting until you find the one that is causing the problem.

If all else fails, the nuclear option is to just remove everything in a `<style>` tag and to delete the contents of your CSS file.

2nd EDIT: The problem is the `&nbsp;` tags throughout. If you do a global find and replace and turn them all into spaces, the problem should go away—it does in the browser, at any rate. The epub reading systems I checked your file on did not have the problem that you mention, so reading systems may vary.

In general: Your file has been autoconverted by or through Microsoft Word. This is a terrible idea. If you need to go through Word, consider going into something better at conversion, like InDesign, or get used to cleaning up the HTML and CSS on your own. There are numerous other design issues throughout the manuscript, not least of which is that all measurements are absolute rather than relative, meaning that it is not possible for readers to change font size. You should also be aware that whatever did the final conversion did not produce a valid epub file, even taking into account that it is epub 2 instead of epub 3. Here is the result from [epubcheck](http://validator.idpf.org/):

```
Validating against EPUB version 2.0
ERROR: ebook.epub/OEBPS/content.opf(7,14): element "metadata" incomplete; missing required elements "dc:language" and "dc:title"
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4728): The character 'NEWLINE' is not allowed in 'STRING' expressions
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4752): The character 'NEWLINE' is not allowed in 'STRING' expressions
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4764): The character 'NEWLINE' is not allowed in 'STRING' expressions
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4729): Token '{' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4753): Token '{' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html(4765): Token '{' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 02.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 03.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 04.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 05.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 06.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 07.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 08.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 09.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 10.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 11.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 12.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 13.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 14.html(1792): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 15.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 16.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 17.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 18.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 19.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 20.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 21.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 22.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 23.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 24.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 25.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 26.html(4708): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 27.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 28.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 29.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 30.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 31.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 32.html(3250): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 33.html(4969): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 33.html(4980): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 34.html(4969): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 34.html(4980): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 35.html(6427): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 35.html(6438): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 36.html(6427): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 36.html(6438): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 37.html(6427): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 37.html(6438): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 38.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 38.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 39.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 39.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 40.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 40.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 41.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 41.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 42.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 42.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 43.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 43.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 44.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 44.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 45.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 45.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 46.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 46.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 47.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 47.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 48.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 48.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 49.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 49.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 50.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 50.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 51.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 51.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 52.html(7885): Token '.10' not allowed here
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 52.html(7896): Token '.15' not allowed here
ERROR: ebook.epub/OEBPS/toc.ncx(19,42): 'OEBPS/Text/Section0001.xhtml': referenced resource missing in the package.
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 17.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 32.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 24.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 48.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 20.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 04.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 18.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 39.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 15.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 29.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 11.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 50.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 47.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 09.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 40.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 31.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 16.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 21.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 41.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 01.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 43.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 44.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 12.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 23.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 35.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 38.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 03.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 27.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 52.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 22.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 37.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 45.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 46.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 13.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 26.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 05.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 51.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 49.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 06.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 34.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 42.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 10.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 08.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 25.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 07.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 28.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 30.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 36.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 14.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 02.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 19.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary
WARNING: ebook.epub/OEBPS/Text/Zondag 33.html: Filename contains spaces. Consider changing filename such that URI escaping is not necessary

Check finished with warnings or errors
```

If you have any further questions, please feel free to open a new question addressing specifically them.

Comment: Hi Tom, I copied text into a text editor (wps writer) and saved it as .html file. Then I imported the html file(s) (the epub consists of 52 html files) into the epub using Sigil. I have the epub in my dropbox, you can find it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52924699/Heidelbergse%20Catechismus.epub. I am looking forward to your feedback. Many thanks in advance already!

Comment: DutchArjo, please update the post here with some representative sample of the code. Any answer I give to you about code that nobody else can see once your dropbox link isn't good anymore will not really serve others who come to this site to get questions answered, you know?

Comment: I will when I get home again tonight. I assume you need code about a part of the text that now is not displayed right... correct?

Comment: Correct, and any relevant CSS as well. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted some part. Because there's a lot more in the html file in the epub, I tried to post the whole html file. But that exceeded the max amount of characters. I know there is a site where you can easily paste a lot of text and link to that in a post. But I cannot remember which site it was..

Comment: I've updated my answer based on what you posted.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have opened the file in chrome. But I do not understand what I have to do. this is what I see: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52924699/chrome%20elements%20section.png and do you have any suggestions for saving my file in html format other then a text editor? (to avoid this situation)

Comment: I've updated my answer for you after looking over the file that you provided.